# Setting a date on the x axis of a graph with matplotlib + tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Having alot of trouble finding a solution that works when trying to put dates along the xaxis. Im not pulling any data from the internet, all of it is coming from a notepad file at the moment. Many of the solutions i have found give me errors, and the youtube videos i have watched explaining how to do this, all draw in information i think by using urllib.

```
Fig = Figure(figsize=(10,4), dpi=80)
a = Fig.add_subplot(111)
Fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.974, top=0.9, bottom=0.1)
Fig.patch.set_visible(False)
a.title.set_text('Graph')
a.set_xlabel('Date')
a.set_ylabel('Cost (GBP)')
```

the code above is the code i currently have to make the graph, before it get overwritten using the code below.

```
  def animate_graph(self, i):
    pullData = open('financeData.txt','r').read()
    dataList = pullData.split('\n')
    xAxisList = []
    yAxisList = []
    taxList = []
    outgoingsList = []
    for eachLine in dataList:
      if len(eachLine) > 1:
        x, y, o= eachLine.split(',')
        xAxisList.append(int(x))
        yAxisList.append(int(y))
        intY = int(y)
        taxGraphData = intY * TAXRATE
        taxList.append(taxGraphData)
        outgoingsList.append(int(o))
    a.clear()
    a.plot(xAxisList, yAxisList, label='Profits line', color='green')
    a.plot(xAxisList, outgoingsList, label='Outgoings line')
    a.plot(xAxisList, taxList, label='Tax line')
    a.title.set_text('Pyraknight Finance Graph')
    a.set_xlabel('Date')
    a.set_ylabel('Cost (GBP)')
    a.legend()
```

And then to place the graph onto my frame i have used the code below

```
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(Fig, graphFrame)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10,sticky='nsew')

self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation (Fig, self.animate_graph, interval=1000)
```

THese are the libraries im importing:

```
#importing tkinter libraries
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox,Treeview,Scrollbar

#importing matplotlib libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

#Other libraries
import hashlib
import sqlite3
import os
import time
import datetime
```

How would i go about adding dates to my x axis? Thanks in advance, Nas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently using this

```
import datetime

ax = plt.gca()
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate(rotation=30)
#stepsize = 2592000 # 30 days
#stepsize = 864000 # 10 days
stepsize = 86400 # 1 day
#stepsize = 3600 # 1 hour
start, end = ax.get_xlim()
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange((end - end%3600), start, -stepsize))
def timestamp(x, pos):
        return (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        #return (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x)).strftime('%m/%d %H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(timestamp))
```

This will plot one labeled tick on every day counting from most recent whole hour back in time.

samples:

[image]
[image]

reference:

http://strftime.org/

http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html

http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter

http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate

http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.XAxis.set_ticks.html